# How to make cms page editor?

Tags: php

for example i have a article in my database. i want to make a system to 
edit that article. i have already made the system which change the content of 
the article but i want to change the color and contents size. or u can say that 
i want to create posting system like PHPbb forum which allow to change color and 
size of content and also allow me to add links. any links of codes and tutorila will be 
great hlep for me thanks.

Comment: You can use simple HTML if it's editing for you. Or you can use [WYSIWYG](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=WYSIWYG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those text editors you can see in phpBB and others are called text formatting toolbars, and together with visible changes, they are called WYSIWYG (WhatYouSeeIsWhatYouGet) editors. There are tons' of ready for use, freeware, PHP based editors out there.

By the way, phpBB one uses special BBCode tag system (PHP based), that uses strict format of specific tags. That is needed for security reasons. But, if you trust people, who input those articles, you can use standart HTML tags, that makes WYSIWYG possible (HTML/JavaScript based).

Answer (score 2):

Try TinyMCE

It should cover your needs